# Same code but different output in Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

Recently i'm develop a program by using Arduino UNO. The code i write for two button is totally same but the output different.

Here is the code i write.

```
const int BUTTON1 = 6;
const int BUTTON2 = 7;
String i, j, x;

int ButtonState = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(BUTTON1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(BUTTON2, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON1) == LOW) {
    delay(500);
    i = "1";
    Serial.println(i);
  } 
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON2) == LOW) {
    delay(500);
    j = "2";
    Serial.println(j);
  } 
  else {
    delay(500);
    x = "0";
    Serial.println(x);
  }
}
```

When i keep pressing the button1, the output is
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0

And when i keep pressing the button2, the ouput is
2
2
2
2
2
2
2

How can i make the output of button1 same with the output of button2?

Comment: Do the Arduino libs handle de-bouncing? Otherwise that's one obvious problem.

Comment: @Lundin No, and there is the answer provided. Thank you also

Comment: @Lundin: delay(500) handles debouncing.

Comment: @datafiddler No, it doesn't. Since this code uses polling, it may read the button at any point in time and not just on an edge. The read might occur in the middle of a signal bounce, and then the button remains in the wrong position for 500ms.

Comment: @Lundin There is no wrong position during bouncing! You get still the old one or already the new one. If I read a button only every 500 ms, I won't notice every change,and yes, it remains in the wrong position for 500 ms, but I don't have to care about bouncing.

Comment: @datafiddler The user will notice it as a broken button, which sometimes fails to register button presses.That's as bad as no debouncing at all.

Comment: If the button is pressed for less than 0.5s, it will be either noticed for 0.5s or not at all. I agree, `delay(500);` is bad for interactive sketches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can i make the output of button1 same with the output of button2?

You are getting `1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0` for `button 1` because first `if` and last `else` block will be executed each time when `button1` is pressed.

Add `else` to second `if`.

```
if (digitalRead(BUTTON1) == LOW) {
    delay(500);
    i = "1";
    Serial.println(i);
  } 
  else if (digitalRead(BUTTON2) == LOW) {
    delay(500);
    j = "2";
    Serial.println(j);
  } 
  else {
    delay(500);
    x = "0";
    Serial.println(x);
  }
```